# Add data from filter to a variable in power bi

Tags: datetime, graph, powerbi

I have created graph with cumulative churn in current month and previos month. I created 2 columns: 
`CurrentMonth and PrevMonth` with values `"Yes"/"No"` and then I filtered data by these columns.

```
CurrentMonth =    
var currentrowyearmonth = FORMAT('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime]; "yyyymm")    
var istoday = FORMAT(MAX('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime]); "yyyymm")    
return if(istoday = currentrowyearmonth; "Yes"; "No")    

PrevMonth =    
var currentrowyearmonth = FORMAT(('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime]); "yyyymm")    
var istoday = FORMAT(EDATE(MAX('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime]); -1); "yyyymm")    
var currentrowday = DAY('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime])    
var maxday = DAY(MAX('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime]))     
return if(istoday = currentrowyearmonth; if(currentrowday <= maxday; "Yes"; "No"); "No")
```

I want to be able plot the same graph for any date selected in the filter. 
For example,

If I chose today's date June will be the current month, and May the previous month. If I chose May 26 May will be the current month, and April the previous month and then the graph is automatically rebuilt.

Later date strings should not be counted.

I need to replace `MAX('Sheet1 (2)'[datetime])` in var `"istoday"` to selected date from filter.

How can I do this or does this task require something else?